# Two different outputs from functions

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;

char* InitializingMatrix(char start, char end) {
    char matrix[9];

    //Initializing random symbols to char massive
    srand((unsigned)time(0));
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        matrix[i] = (int)start + rand() % (int)end;

    //Output matrix
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        (i == 3 || i == 6) ? cout << endl << (char)matrix[i] << " " : cout << (char)matrix[i] << " ";
    cout << endl;

    return matrix;
}

void Output(char matrix[]) {
    //Output matrix
    for (int i = 0; i < 9; i++)
        (i == 3 || i == 6) ? cout << endl << (char)matrix[i] << " " : cout << (char)matrix[i] << " ";
}


int main() {
    Output(InitializingMatrix('1', '6'));
    return 0;
}
```

**Problem**

The output of the matrix from the function for initializing the matrix and from the function for outputting the matrix are different.

**Questions**

Why output from InitializingMatrix and Output have differences?

How to fix it?

Comment: [What is a debugger and how can it help me diagnose problems?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25385173/what-is-a-debugger-and-how-can-it-help-me-diagnose-problems)

Comment: You return dangling pointer.

Comment: Returning `std::array<char, 9>` would avoid the issue.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub

Comment: [Why is "using namespace std;" considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: [Warnings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57842756/why-should-i-always-enable-compiler-warnings) are your friends. [Enable them](https://godbolt.org/z/8M98Kc1Yz).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue that you return a `Pointer` but you allocate a `Value`.

Allocation:

```cpp
char matrix[9];
```

Return value:

```
char* InitializingMatrix(...)
```

Type `char matrix[]` is a compiled time array.
If you wish to use arrays you'll need to use `new char()` instead to dynamically allocate a new array.

The `C++ OOP` way is to use a class:

1. Use the built in type `std::array<...>`
2. Create a class and save the array in there:

```cpp
struct MyData 
{
  char Data[10];
}
```

The compiler would help you pass this around by value or use a `ref` to pass it by reference instead:

```cpp
MyData Initialize() { ... };

void Output(MyData& data);
//or
void Output(const MyData& data);

int main() 
{
    MyData data = Initialize();
    Output(data );
    return 0;
}
```

3. The more professional way is to use built-in types or frameworks that exist,
   If you need a matrix you can use libraries like `GMTL` or `EIGEN`

Comment: almost all of this is bad advice, or simply wrong

Comment: @NeilButterworth Can you be more specific?

Comment: @NeilButterworth Refrain from making such comments without explaining yourself.